# Pattern matching expressions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Im making my way throught functional programming in JS. Recently I started to use Daggy to accomplish simple pattern matching, but I don't think that I fully get it.

Given this code:

```
  if(a === 1 && !b) {
   do(y)
  }

   if(b === 3 && c === 2) {
    do(z)
  }

  if (a) { 
    do(x) 
  }
```

Is there a way to improve this cohercions into something similar to?:

```
   when [a === 1 && !b] : do(y)
   when [a] : do(x)
   when [b === 3 && c === 2]: do(z)
```

Comment: `do` is a reserved keyword... you'll get a `SyntaxError`, and `when` is not a keyword

Comment: What a "cohercion"?

Comment: You can ditch the curly braces if you only have a single statement in the block: `if (a === 1 && !b) go(y);`

Comment: "Improve" in what sense? All you've done is change `if` to `when`, used `[]` instead of `()` on the condition, and used `:` instead of either leaving it off entirely (an `if` with no block) or using a block. You can write the `if`s on one line if you like (https://pastebin.com/TxMnum54) or even abuse the `&&` operator if you like (https://pastebin.com/FgjfGufe), neither of which is more "functional" nor (IMHO) an improvement. (I've changed `do` to `foo` in those, see @CertainPerformance's comment). Also added missing semicolons, the second form in particular is not going to work with ASI.

Comment: If those are exclusive, you'll want `else`.

Comment: Check https://datarockets.com/blog/javascript-pattern-matching-library-daggy/

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't have the kind of pattern matching you're probably talking about. There is [an active proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching) to add it using `case`/`when`, here's an example from that proposal:

```
const res = await fetch(jsonService)
case (res) {
  when {status: 200, headers: {'Content-Length': s}} -> {
    console.log(`size is ${s}`)
  }
  when {status: 404} -> {
    console.log('JSON not found')
  }
  when {status} if (status >= 400) -> {
    throw new RequestError(res)
  }
}
```

It's currently just at Stage 1 of [the process](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/), though, so it may not proceed, may change radically before proceeding, and may take years to work through the stages and get into the language. There's work on a [Babel plugin](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/9010).

I'm afraid it's not immediately clear to me how I'd apply it to your example, though, as it seems to want an operand for `case`.

In the meantime, a series of `if`/`else if` can be fairly terse if terseness is what you're looking for:

```
if (a === 1 && !b)           foo(y);
else if (a)                  foo(x);
else if (b === 3 && c === 2) foo(z);
```

Or JavaScript's `switch` is unusually flexible (it's really just another way to write `if`/`else if`):

```
switch (true) {
    case a === 1 && !b:      foo(y); break;
    case a:                  foo(x); break;
    case b === 3 && c === 2: foo(z); break;
}
```

(I'm not advocating it, just pointing out it's an option.)

Comment: Since [these proposed features](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching) have not yet been added to JavaScript, I use the [ex-patterns](https://moritzploss.github.io/ex-patterns/#/) library instead. It has a very similar `match` / `when` syntax for pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class to your data and then use functions to check the conditions and do an action in case that the particular condition meets.

Simple and easy, without any libraries.

```js
class typeWrap {

  constructor(obj) {
    this.var  =  obj;
    this.done = false;
  }

  when (condition, doFn) {

    if (!this.done && condition(this.var)) {
      this.done = true;
      doFn(this.var);
    }
    return this;
  }
}

const data = new typeWrap({
  b: 3, c : 9
});

data
  .when(
    d => d.a === 1 && !d.b,
    () => console.log('C1 => y')
  )
  .when(
    d => d.b === 3 && d.c !== 2,
    () => console.log('C2 => z')
  )
  .when(
    d => d.a,
    () => console.log('C3 => x')
  )
  .when(
    d => true,
    () => console.log('Last stop')
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure with Daggy you could define Maybe

```
    const Maybe = daggy.taggedSum('Option', {
        Just: ['a'],
        Nothing: []
    })
```

and then define a prototype function on it called `alt` which can basically fallback to the passed value

```
    // alt :: Alt f => f a ~> f a -> f a
    Maybe.prototype.alt = function(o): Maybe<T> {
        return this.cata({
          Just: _ => this,
          Nothing: () => o
        })
      }
```

So with it we can do some pattern matching or similar

```
    function match(comparator, res) {
      switch (comparator()) {
        case true: return Maybe.of(res)
        case false: return Maybe.Nothing
        default: return Maybe.Nothing
      }

    }
```

```
    MaybeF.Nothing
      .alt(match(() => a === 1 && !b, () => y))
      .alt(match(() => a, () => x))
      .alt(match(() => b === 3 && c === 2, () => z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Developer and maintainer of Patroon. I was looking for js style pattern matching and had to build my own. This is what your example would look like using the patroon library:

```js
const isNil = x => !(x != null)

patroon(
  {a: 1, b: isNil}, y,
  {b: 3, c: 2}, z,
  {a: _}, x
)({a, b, c})
```

https://github.com/bas080/patroon